# Connecting to on-prem calendar from 365 account

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration, office365

Good morning folks.
We've got a weird situation and I can't find a way round it.
*The client* has had a partial migration to 365 - mailboxes for three domains were hosted in Exchange 2013 and those from one were migrated to 365. It's not a hybrid setup and the original mailboxes were kept even though they're not used (that caused delivery problems email from on-prem to the migrated domain but they're fixed).
At least one migrated user needs access to the calendar (details, not just free/busy) of a non-migrated user, and I can't find a way.
Can anyone come up with something we could do, or should we just push hard for migrating the rest?
Or is there some way I've never seen to make it hybrid *after the fact*?
Cheers

Comment: I set up a sharing policy but I've not heard back yet on whether or not it worked. The client has agreed though to migrate the mailboxes in the second domain, so the whole thing will soon be moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version of Exchange is running on premises, but I'll assume it's at least Exchange Server 2013.

Also, I'm not quite understanding your scenario. You say that one domain has been migrated to Office 365... but you don't migrate domains to Office 365. You migrate mailboxes, public folders, etc. to Office 365. Do you mean that you added and verified one of the domains in Office 365, created users, assigned Exchange Online capable licenses to these users, and then deleted the on premises mailboxes for these users? So now all email for this domain is being delivered directly to Office 365? And you need these users to have access to the on premises mailbox calendars?

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you'll need to set up sharing by using either an organization relationship or by configuring a sharing policy.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/sharing-exchange-2013-help

Comment: Thanks for the many lessons in clarity. Your assumptions are correct, except that the local mailboxes were never deleted. Nor were the email addresses which caused delivery issues, but I've dealt with that.  
I don't know why it was done this way instead of hybrid, but as far as I know this is only needed for one pair of users. We're trying to make the case for completing the migration so I think the sharing policy is the way to go. I'll take a look at that today.

Answer (score 1):

Which method do you use to migrate mailboxes?
Since you didn’t deploy hybrid , the migrated mailboxes and on-premises mailboxes are still from two organization. So they cannot share calendar directly. You could refer to the following article:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/matabra/2013/05/07/cross-premise-calendar-sharing-with-office-365/

It is better to deploy hybrid.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01c2fd04-c818-46f2-af19-844b0b09f766/calendar-sharing-with-office-365-in-hybrid?forum=Exch2016GD

Comment: Believe me I'd have deployed Hybrid, but the migration was done before I joined the company.

Comment: But you said “It's not a hybrid setup”? If now it is hybrid deployment, you could re-run HCW to make sure the configuration is correct, and the F/B info is working in hybrid deployment by default.

Comment: No, it's not hybrid, I was just saying that's what _I_ would have done.